# Programmatically move an artifact from one repo to another

Tags: java, maven, nexus, aether

I need to write a Java program that takes an artifact from a given Nexus repository, including the pom and all side artifacts (like sources, javadoc, whatever) and moves it to a different repository.

I guess that Aether would be a good start, but I don't know how to handle the combined set of files (main artifact, pom, sources,...) in a straight-forward way.

Comment: Is that on the same nexus instance?

Comment: It is. I thought about working on the file level and reindex the repositories afterwards, but I am not sure if this is a good idea.

Comment: It's best to move those files on the storage of Nexus and start a reindex on the appropriate repositories in Nexus..is simpler than making a whole set of files from outside.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot something important: The source repository is a remote repository. So probably I have to download the artifact first to be able to move it from one directory to the other.